# How do i load bootstrap in child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component, `dashboard` and within that component I have generated another component,`menu-bar` (which has only the html of that side menu) that I intend to use in other components. If I call the menu bar like this:

`<app-menu-bar> </ app-menu-bar>`

The bootstrap does not load for this component that was called, but for the rest of the page it loads normally. But if I get the html from the `menu-bar` component and put it inside the`dashboard` html it works normally. What should I do? I need to do something different to load the bootstrap into a child component?

Note: I load the bootstrap ( bootstrap CSS ) inside the `angular.json` and it works normally for other components

Comment: With bootstrap you mean "Bootstrap CSS"?...

Comment: Yeah, bootstrap css

Comment: So, we know that it loads bootstrap correctly, and it works on the parent component but not in child, is child actually being called correctly and the console not showing any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of default style encapsulation of Angular component.

You could open `dashboard.component.ts` or your dashboard ts file

Add `ViewEncapsulation.None` or `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` depends on your usage. You could refer to [this](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
...
```